# How to perform hot patch using RPM in linux

Tags: patch, rpm

I have to build an rpm and install. Some times I need replace only few files of already installed package. Is there an option to replace only desired files while installing it. I have an option to build patch with required files.

Not sure what the bellow option provies

```
--replacefiles
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Upload the tar file to the patch server
- Save the metadata of the patch server
- Connect to the deployment server
- Download the patch tarball using the metadata previously saved
- Search the file tree of the package to be patched
- Update the RPM Spec File to Apply the Patch
- Build the RPM

**References**

- [HowTo Create A Patch File For A RPM - NST Wiki](http://wiki.networksecuritytoolkit.org/index.php/HowTo_Create_A_Patch_File_For_A_RPM)
- [linux - Bash script to verify that an rpm is at least at a given version - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163702/bash-script-to-verify-that-an-rpm-is-at-least-at-a-given-version)
- [Fedora RPM Guide - Chapter 12. Supplemental Packaging Software: Using VIM spec plugins to improve spec file editing](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch-extra-packaging-tools.html#id601565)
- [package management - Is it possible to modify/rebuild an rpm without the srpm? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/133317/is-it-possible-to-modify-rebuild-an-rpm-without-the-srpm)
- [Packaging Guide - Software Collections](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/docs/guide/)